# Google Chrome: Adding custom image in the tab container

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, themes

I am trying to customize my Google Chrome browser by adding an image at the very top in the tab container above the search bar. I notice a few themes in the Theme store have images, but I couldn't find how to add custom images from any online source

I also noticed that every time I installed a theme, a file would get downloaded into my computer. I'm not sure where to find this file but could I modify the code to get the desired changes?

Comment: Those are themes, see the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/themes). Extensions can't do it.

Comment: @wOxxOm It seems to require an extension and the `manifest.json` file but it's really complicated

Comment: Just take an existing theme (maybe from the example) and modify it. No need for extensions.

Comment: @wOxxOm Hmm do you know how to modify an existing theme? I think that's a really good idea but I'm not sure how to access source code

Comment: [These tutorials](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+modify+an+existing+chrome+extension) should help.